# Templates won't change unless server is restarted?

Tags: node.js, templates, nunjucks

I am used to using jinja2 and flask in python so I opted for nunjucks when I started doing a web-project in node. But the problem is whenever I change something in the template files the changes will not appear on the browser on page refresh but instead I have to manually restart the server every time.

Is there any specific configuration should I use

I have configured nunjucks as below

```
//nunjucks
app.engine("views", nunjucks.render);
app.set("view engine", "html");
nunjucks.configure("views", {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app,
});
```

I am also using `nodemon` in my dev server and its totally being useless because of this should I change the configuration of nunjucks or something?

Comment: Read [man](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure) and try `noCache` and `watch` set as `true`.

Comment: Thank you setting the watch as true did work.